# Google Apps Script Calendar Service: Get the start date of a recurring (all day) event

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476850/google-apps-script-calendar-service-find-first-event-in-calendareventseries). Is it still not possible to retrieve the start date of a recurring (all day) event in standard mode (without enabling "Advanced Google services")?

Comment: I don't see any method in the documentation for getting the start date using the built-in CalendarApp Service : [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series.html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series.html)

Comment: Do you have the [CalendarEventSeries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series.html) ID or object? Or you want the start date for all recurring events series?

Comment: Not beforehand. I want to loop through all recurring (all day) events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do it:

```
function findFirstEvent() {
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar Id");
  var startTime=new Date(1850,0,1);
  var endTime=new Date();
  var events=cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime,{search:'Keywords contained in the event or just the title'});
  Logger.log('StartTime: %s, Id: %s',events[0].getStartTime(),events[0].getId());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this approach preferable compared with using "Advanced Google services" and `.start`?

Comment: I think it's a personal choice.