# Google Apps Script Calendar Service: Get only the first events of all recurring (all day) events

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, calendar

In addition to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60241490/google-apps-script-calendar-service-get-the-start-date-of-a-recurring-all-day) I'd like to ask how to efficiently retrieve only the first events of all recurring (all day) events. To call the function `findFirstEvent()` for each single event seems not to be reasonable. So my approach would be to filter the array of all events.

```
var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Calendar Id");
var startTime=new Date(1850,0,1);
var endTime=new Date();
var events=cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
var firstEvents=events.filter(onlyFirstEvents);

function onlyFirstEvents() {
    ...
}
```

What I actually need in the end is an array with the event titles as keys and `Date` objects as values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve all recurring events and all day events from a Google calendar.
- Especially, You want to retrieve the date object of the start event of the recurring event.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, the methods of `isRecurringEvent()` and `isAllDayEvent()` are used.
- `getEvents()` returns the events with the descending order. Using this, the result you expect is retrieved.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var firstEvents=events.filter(onlyFirstEvents);
```

To:

```
var firstEvents = events.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  var id = e.getId();
  if (e.isRecurringEvent() && e.isAllDayEvent() && !ar.some(function(f) {return f.eventId == id})) {
    ar.push({eventTitle: e.getTitle(), eventId: id, startDate: e.getAllDayStartDate(), endDate: e.getAllDayEndDate()});
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
```

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following value is returned.

```
[
  {
    "eventTitle": "###",
    "eventId": "###",
    "startDate": ### date object ###,
    "endDate": ### date object ###
  },
,
,

]
```

#### References:

- [isRecurringEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#isrecurringevent)
- [isAllDayEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#isAllDayEvent())
- [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getid)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

- So you would for loop through the result array firstEvents to get the desired array with the event titles as keys and Date objects as values?

From this, I cannot understand whether you want an array or an object. So I would like to propose 2 patterns. In this case, I thought that `firstEvents` of the current script can be used.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, an array, which includes that the event titles and the start date object are the key and value, respectively, is returned. Please modify as follows.

Script:

```
var firstEvents = events.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  var id = e.getId();
  if (e.isRecurringEvent() && e.isAllDayEvent() && !ar.some(function(f) {return f.eventId == id})) {
    ar.push({eventTitle: e.getTitle(), eventId: id, startDate: e.getAllDayStartDate(), endDate: e.getAllDayEndDate()});
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
firstEvents = firstEvents.map(function(e) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[e.eventTitle] = e.startDate;
  return obj;
});
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, an object, which includes that the event titles and the start date object are the key and value, respectively, is returned.

Script:

```
var firstEvents = events.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  var id = e.getId();
  if (e.isRecurringEvent() && e.isAllDayEvent() && !ar.some(function(f) {return f.eventId == id})) {
    ar.push({eventTitle: e.getTitle(), eventId: id, startDate: e.getAllDayStartDate(), endDate: e.getAllDayEndDate()});
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
firstEvents = firstEvents.reduce(function(obj, e) {
  obj[e.eventTitle] = e.eventTitle in obj ? obj[e.eventTitle].concat(e.startDate) : [e.startDate];
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: Your answer is exemplary neat. Thank you very much!

Doesn't `getEvents()` return the events in ascending order?

So you would `for` loop through the result array `firstEvents` to get the desired array with the event titles as keys and `Date` objects as values?

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying and pointing out my English. I thought that I might have misunderstood "ascending" and "descending". I had wanted to say that the 1st index of the array retrieved by `getEvents()` is oldest event. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. About `the desired array with the event titles as keys and Date objects as values`, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize again.

Comment: Actually I wasn't referring to your English but to the well-arranged form of your answer as well as to your politeness. But anyway, your English is probably much better than mine. With the first event beeing the oldest, I would refer to the order as ascending, but that could be a matter of opinion. Pattern 1 is just fine. Thank you very much! By the way, there is no need to apologize at all. :)

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: It seems as if `firstEvents` holds not only the first events of event series but also the respectively (currently) last ones!?

Comment: @Ben Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to study more and try to understand about it.

Comment: It was my fault. I'm sorry!